# link header in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to use header file (it is wiringPi library for gnio). I am using Eclipse with C++. I tried to add header like this, please advise where I am wrong or what is missing. I have already added path for header files as Properties > C/C++ Build >Settings > Include.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not that good at Eclipse, but I would have put the C++ includes under g++ and not under gcc.

Comment: I have tried both ways, g++ and gcc. But, I do not see GCC linker in setting(you can also see in above snaps)!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using `#include <wiring.h>` but the correct syntax for C++ when including headers is `#include "wiring.h"`.